# How do you get Hinges in SOD?

Tags: state-of-decay

I am curious on how to get hinges in State of Decay. Where exactly are they located? I need them to get the Medical Camp (or for anything). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most facilities will run into a 'facility need' when being built. This is a random item that you should go find to speed things up, such as 'hinges'.

On your map there will be a question mark. Select it, and it will highlight locations that may contain the item you're looking for. The item will be in a container in one of these locations, so you should fully search each of them.

Each type of random item has a particular container that it tends to be in. Hinges, for instance, are usually in containers that tend to contain construction materials. These include those big piles of wood and buckets, toolboxes, wooden crates, etc.

It *is* possible to find the random item you're looking for in one of these containers *not* in the indicated search locations. I will sometimes leave a construction materials container unsearched near my base, and just go check it when I need hinges or duct tape or whatever. This saves me a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

Check on your map, there should be a magnifying glass icon. When you hover your mouse over it question marks will appear on the map indicating locations where you can find hinges.

Answer (score 0):

When building facilities, you sometimes will need to acquire a random component.

It will spawn at a random location on the map, though if you ignore it, the facilities will eventually be completed by itself. However, manually getting and delivering the component will cut down construction time considerably.

For more details you can refer to the game's [wiki page](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Facilities#Special_Components)